# Modal backdrop doesn't hide when clicking an element inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

On a page I have a modal with few `<div class="message-container">`. If the user clicks on that element, the page sends AJAX request for new modal. But when I close a new modal, I still have the backdrop from the first modal.
All modals return PHP. I have also tried closing the old modal before opening a new one but that still doesn't help.

Here is the JS code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.message-container', function () {
    var messageId = $(this).attr('data-message-id');
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            action: 'readMessage',
            messageId: messageId
        }
    }).done(function (ret) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(ret);
        if (obj.code == 1) {
            $('#messages').modal('hide');
            $('.modal-container').html('');

            $('.modal-container').html(obj.value);
            $('#read-message').modal('toggle');
        } else {

        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.unreadedMessages', function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            action: 'getMessages'
        }
    }).done(function (ret) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(ret);
        if (obj.code == 1) {
            $('.modal-container').html(obj.value);
            $('#messages').modal('show');
        } else {
            var content = '<div class="alert alert-danger" id="messages-alert" role="alert">' + obj.value + '</div>';
        }
    })
});
```

unreadedMessages is first.

Comment: To which `url` you are doing `ajax` post??

Comment: To default url. I have a function to distribute request to correct method.

Comment: You might need to post your modal `html` too to understand it properly

Comment: Add backticks (`\``) around inline HTML code to avoid them from being treated as normal HTML markup (and be hidden from view). Library names are not required in title because they are part of tags. Avoid *thanks* nots because they are considered as fluff and are not required. Finally, you don't have to say *I have a problem*. It is understood :)

Comment: Sorry about the *please format code* comment earlier. It was an oversight on my part. Coming to the question's content, I couldn't quite understand this statement - *unreadedMessages is first.*. Please clarify further if it is important information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but here is a CSS pattern that I used when I have multiple modals open.

```
body .modalBlockout ~ .modalBlockout {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

This will hide any extra block out elements, and only shows the first one.